# Finding general solution of elementary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can this equation be solved using extended linearity principle?

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} - 2y = 7e^{2t} $$

I found the general solution to the homogeneous portion: $ y = ke^{2t} $.

But finding a particular solution to the nonhomogeneous equation is difficult, as the terms keep cancelling out.

Is this a candidate for the methodology of integrating factors?

Comment: Try $cte^{2t}$. Integrating factors are fine too.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Good suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the inhomogeneous part of your ODE is of the form $Ae^{bt}$, a good guess for your particular solution is $ce^{bt}$, unless your homogeneous solution already has that as its form. In this case, the standard method is to multiply by $t$, and guess $cte^{bt}$ as your particular solution. If you guess, as Andre Nicolas suggests, $ct e^{2t}$ as your particular solution, you will not get complete cancellation, and you will be able to determine the value of $c$.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use integrating factors method (as suggested by Andre):

Using Integrating factor: $e^{-2t}$
$$  \frac{d}{dt}ye^{-2t} = 7$$

$$ ye^{-2t} = \int 7 \ dt = 7t + C $$

$$ y = e^{2t}(7t + C)$$

where $C$ is constant of integration